# Is the ability to debug stored procedures considered somehow frivolous?

Tags: sql-server, devops

I am working on some stored procedures at a client site.

To debug stored procedures using SSMS, it seems you must be a member of the [sysadmin] group.  However, they only have PROD and TEST database instances, and the DBA will not grant me these permissions.

According to him, using inline PRINT statements is considered to be just as good as the ability to debug.  That doesn't seem quite right to me so I was thinking of escalating my request, but thought I'd first ask here, is this common sentiment in the industry (that the ability to debug is "not necessary")?

Comment: You could put Developer edition on your workstation and work with your own copy of the database so you could use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Though bit opinion based question but **yes** I have always used debug like that ... that is get the procedure body and run each code block separately to find where the problem is and fix accordingly.

You might also want to consider the execution plan of the procedure which will help in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, yes.

I once found the debugging functionality very useful when I was transitioning from being a ASP developer to a SQL developer, but as I've become more comfortable with SQL, I find that I can do all my debugging with PRINT statements.

Also in addition to being a sysadmin, did you know that you have to be running the debugger locally on the SQL server to use it?  It's a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: "did you know that you have to be running the debugger locally on the SQL server to use it?"   Wow, if true that is another big drawback.

Comment: "I find that I can do all my debugging with PRINT statements"  Just out of curiosity:  when debugging in SSMS, you can see all your variables in the locals window, without having to write any PRINT statements.  Would you consider having to write PRINT statements for each variable (in multiple places as the value can change) to be functionally identical to having them automatically displayed in the locals window?

Comment: Well I considered adding that very thought to my answer, and decided it was too verbose.  But yes, the only thing the debugger gives you is the ability to see what is in your variables at any given point in your code, and you can do exactly that with PRINT statements.

Comment: > you can do exactly that with PRINT statements
Yes, provided you a PRINT statement after literally every single line of TSQL, outputting literally every single variable name and value.  Not exactly what I'd call reasonable. :)

Comment: Literally, I'd agree.   But in practice, and in my experience, I've never need to use more than 3 or 4 PRINT statements in even the longest and most complex stored procedures I write.  I don't pre-load my procs with every PRINT statement I might possibly need.   If a proc is getting an error, I can always figure out where and why with just a few PRINT statements.   But again, I'm not a beginner any more.   I might not have been able to do this 10 years ago.  Anyway, the question is: "is this common sentiment?", and in my experience, the answer is "yes".